# A program that allows an emulated folder to be placed on the desktop?

Tags: windows-xp, desktop-environment

First question on this SE, so sorry if this is outside the scope, but I'm looking for a Desktop add-on that allows a user to place a folder from one location onto the desktop, and then have it display the entire folder on the desktop.

For instance, if I have a folder named D:\Documents and Settings\Username\Desktop, it would be able to place that Desktop on the real Desktop and it would show me all the folders in that "Desktop" folder (basically I have to reinstall Windows XP a lot because of a bad sound card so I want a virtual desktop where all the files are on another drive).

For years I thought that [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/) had this functionality, but after thoroughly searching, I can't find a webpage that says it does.

Comment: For which version of windows is this for? Also, this question should be on topic :)

Comment: Windows XP primarily, though I might use it on Windows 7 (to clean up the 40 text documents I have in place of sticky-notes...).

Comment: So basically something like the [KDE FolderView Widget](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xvmvQ.jpg), but for Windows?

Comment: Yes @Timmy! I'm almost positive that I've seen someone using an app like this on Windows, but as I said I could only think of Rainmeter.

Comment: KDE is also [available on Windows](http://download.kde.org/stable/kdewin/installer/kdewin-installer-gui-latest.exe.mirrorlist). I'm in the middle of installing it to see if this widget works and post an answer

Comment: @NobleUplift No success with KDE. See my answer for how to do it with toolbars

Answer (score 1):

You could create desktop toolbars on Windows XP. Here is how:

1. Right click on the taskbar, choose `toolbars` then `New Toolbar...`
2. Navigate to the desired folder and hit `OK`
3. Unlock the taskbar, and drag the folder toolbar onto the desktop

The result should look like this:

[image]

You could resize the toolbar or drag it to the edges of the screen and it will snap to a horizontal or vertical bar. There is also the option to set it always on top

Comment: I'll try this next time my Windows XP box is hooked up.